# ことにする tenses nuances

Tags: grammar, tense

What are the nuances related to tense change about these sentences :

- 早く起きることにしました。
- 早く起きることにします。
- 早く起きることにしています。

Do the intensity or moment of the decision is different for each form ?

Comment: Related: [Present vs. past tense with certain verbs?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13115/43676)